# Two projections in same IQueryable

Tags: linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

Is it possible to have two projections, `.Select(...)`, in one same query?

```
        int total = ...;

        var sendersInfo = db.Persons
            .Select(p => new
            {
                sentSMS = p.SentSMS.Count(...large expression...),
            })
            // Calculate percentages
            .Select(i => new
            {
                sentSMS = i.sentSMS,
                percentage = i.sentSMS/total * 100
            });
```

The above is not working because apparently "i.sentSMS" isn't calculated yet and so a 0 (zero) is being used instead of the result.

What I'm trying to avoid is this (below), which **does** work, but has repeated code "...large expression...":

```
        int total = ...;

        var sendersInfo = db.Persons
            .Select(p => new
            {
                sentSMS = p.SentSMS.Count(...large expression...),
                percentage = p.SentSMS.Count(...large expression...) / total * 100
            });
```

Beside my question ("is it possible..."), is there a best way to achieve this? I don't like uggly code. Also I'm trying to achieve this in pure Linq-to-entities (no linq-to-objects)

Comment: this solved the problem: (float)i.sentSMS/(float)total * 100,  should I delete the question or this may help someone out there in the world?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Commenting on your comment:

You do not need to cast to float every time - as soon as one of the operands is a float, the other is promoted, so the result is of type which bears a higher precision (float > int).

There are two arithmetic operations in line:

```
i.sentSMS / total * 100
//       (1)     (2)
```

Division, then multiplying. Both operators `/` and `*` have the same priority (refer to e.g. [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence)), so the expression is evaluated from the left side, first computing the quotient (because both dividend and divisor are `int`, the result is also `int`), then multiplying the result with `100` (also `int`).

So, instead of doing

```
(float)i.sentSMS / (float)total * 100
```

It suffices to do:

```
//     ┌─ (float) thanks to casting
//     │           ┌─ (int) -> (float) promotion here, making the result of division a (float) too
//     │           │       ┌─ then 100 gets promoted in the second step the same way
(float)i.sentSMS / total * 100
```

And even shorter so:

```
// ┌─ (float) literal, because 100 is an (int) literal and 100.0 (or 100d) is a (double) literal
// │   ┌─ (int) -> (float) promotion
// │   │           ┌─ and again
100f * i.sentSMS / total
```

`100f` being a literal for `float` (same as `(float)100`, but neater) :)

In my opinion `100.0` looks even better, but it is a literal for `double`, even greater precision, so all the `float`s will get promoted to `double`, making the result `double` as well, and so you would get a compiler warning for losing precision while assigning `double` result to `float` variable.